# How can I search the post title and tag using WP_query in wordpress?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am currently implementing a search function to **search the post from wordpress**

I would like to **search the post by Tag , by title and return it as JSON**

I found a plugin that generates the result as JSON (JSON API)

http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#2.1.-Core-controller-methods

In that plugin , there is a get_posts function that can return the query that supports WP_query parameter

I tried a query like that

http://MyWordpressSite.com/?json=get_posts&status=published&orderby=date&order=DESC&lang=en&s=eng&tag=eng&cat=9,10,14,15

where the &s= is the keyword to search while the &tag= is the tag to search

However, there are two problems

1. How can I limit the search to title only? 
   http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter

From the official website, it state search keyword ,but not limit to title only

1. It seems the condition is tag "AND" keywords are match, but what I would like to achieve is tag "OR" keywords are match

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

So, to sum up , the goal is to search the post by Tag , by title and return it as JSON (actually is call the php through JSON), it doesnt matter using the plugin or not, any way achieve the goal is welcomed. Thanks for helping

Comment: I've never used that plugin, but have you tried comma separating multiple ids with commas (`id=9,10,7`), or listing the id parameter multiple times (`id[]=9&id[]=10`)?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion , tried both but not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532825/search-posts-based-on-multiple-categories-wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into plugin functions, This plugin does not support to get posts from multiple category. It just get one category by ID and return the posts and this category info. You need to make a custom plugin or try another to do this task.

Comment: I tried http://test.com/?json=get_posts&cat=9,14 but it seems I can not set a limit on each category. e.g. for each category, get the first 5 record. Thanks.

Comment: `public function get_category_posts() {
    global $json_api;
    $category = $json_api->introspector->get_current_category();
    if (!$category) {
      $json_api->error("Not found.");
    }
    $posts = $json_api->introspector->get_posts(array(
      'cat' => $category->id
    ));
    return $this->posts_object_result($posts, $category);
}`
It's function for your request "get_category_posts", as you can see it just use only one category, if we change $category->id become a string include a list of category id,  your problem will be solve